# PROBLEMA CON FILTRADO CON MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo esa setencia sql que me trae todos los jugadores y sus promedios

```
SELECT j.apellido, j.nombre, j.id_jugador, p.partidos_jugado, c.nombre_club as club,
j.puesto, pj.cant_partido as cantidad_partidos, 
ROUND(SUM(p.valoracion) / pj.cant_partido, 2) as promedio, 
SUM(p.valoracion) as total_valorado 
FROM partido p 
JOIN jugador j ON p.id_jugador = j.id_jugador 
JOIN club c ON j.club = c.id_club 
JOIN partidos_jugados pj ON pj.id_jugador_p = j.id_jugador 
GROUP BY j.apellido, j.nombre, c.nombre_club, j.puesto, pj.cant_partido 
ORDER BY j.apellido, j.nombre
```

por ejemplo aca hay un jugador que tiene 3 partidos jugados una valoración total de 25 y un promedio de 8.33

el problema es cuando filtro por destacado_p = 1 que esta en la tabla partido.

cuando pongo:

```
SELECT j.apellido, j.nombre, j.id_jugador, p.partidos_jugado,
c.nombre_club as club, j.puesto, pj.cant_partido as cantidad_partidos,
ROUND(SUM(p.valoracion) / pj.cant_partido, 2) as promedio,
SUM(p.valoracion) as total_valorado FROM partido p
JOIN jugador j ON p.id_jugador = j.id_jugador
JOIN club c ON j.club = c.id_club
JOIN partidos_jugados pj ON pj.id_jugador_p = j.id_jugador
WHERE p.destacado_p = 1
```

en esa consulta ya cambia, muestra por ejemplo el jugador con 3 partidos jugados una valoración total de 16 y un promedio de 5.33

osea parece que no esta contabilizando un partido.

La idea es que me muestre todos los jugadores descatados con todos los partidos y el promedio y todavia no logro hacer eso, ya probe con varias setencias, varias consultas y nada, ya me quemo el celebro.

Alguien que sabe mas de sql me podria ayudar.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: lo digo sin conocer a fondo el modelo, pero me parece que filtrar por `p..destacado_p = 1` no te puede dar un jugador destacado por partido. Si 1 significa destacado, quizás esa columna te pueda ayudar a filtrar _partidos destacados_, pero no jugadores destacados. Si, por el contrario, esa columna es el jugador destacado del partido, entonces tendría que dar el ID de ese jugador o el número en la camisola, o algo que ayude a relacionar al jugador, y por tanto 1 no puede significar destacado. Sé que esto no resuelve tu problema, pero no se puede resolver sin entender qué es esa columna.

Comment: Hola. Para este tipo de preguntas considera aportar [un ejemplo en línea](https://dbfiddle.uk/3aMmxpPT) con un pequeño set de datos de todas las tablas implicadas y la consulta que estás intentando.

Comment: Hola, ya resolvi, muchas gracias a todos